# C# - Best way for handling multiple methods and its completion

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that have several methods which checks for various errors on a computer. Right now i am calling the methods on load event of the form, but i kinda want to display what the program is doing by updating a label text for everything it does, like a progressbar. It should go from method to method in order.

And later i also want to check if everything has runned successfully. Should i look into Threading Tasks for this? Like starting a task for each method, stopping the task if it fails?

Comment: Why not try it out? everything has pros and cons, try it out and see what happens

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: async/await may be helpful

Comment: I don't think this post is too broad, my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create the following classes:

- `WorkstationCheckBase` - should be the base class for all checks.
- `WorkstationCheckRunner` - gets a list of all checks and summarize
  the result of each `WorkstationCheckBase`.

With that, you will encapsulate the checking from your UI and separete these concepts.

Now for you second question to show up on the UI some information (my assumation is that you use WinForm). For that you need a background task and update the UI frequently. You could use the `Backgroundworker` class for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: No, don't use threading-

**Long answer**: It depends!
When you get yourself into threading you start to face loads of other concurrency related problems, if all you want is to show a label of what is happening I would not suggest to use threads.

Since I have no code to look at I can only give you suggestions for how to solve your problem (without threading). The simplest way would be:

```
    public void CheckErrors()
    {
        string errorText = string.Empty;
        if (ErrorOneHasOccured(out errorText))
        {
            ErrorLabel += errorText;
        }

        errorText = string.Empty;
        if (ErrorTwoHasOccured(out errorText))
        {
            ErrorLabel += errorText;
        }
    }

    private bool ErrorOneHasOccured(out string errorText)
    {
        bool errorHasOccured = false;
        errorText = string.Empty;

        // DO error checking somehting

        if (errorHasOccured)
        {
            errorText = "An error description";
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Where :

- ErrorLabel is the string property for the error text you want to display.
- ErrorOneHasOccured is an example method for error checking, using the "Try" pattern.

I think this is the simplest way you can do it, but you can obviously engineer it further depending on what and why you need it.